# Taking user inputs, matching with JSON data and showing result in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating a form in javascript where I am asking to select his gender (radio button) and occupation (dropdown) 
Gender:

```
<p>  Choose Your Gender:</p>
Male <input type="radio" id="gender_male" name="gender" value="male"/> 
Female <input type="radio" id="gender_female" name="gender" value="female"/>
```

Occupation:

```
<label id= "occupation"> Choose Your Occupation: </label> 
<select> 
<option value="productiontrans">Production, Transportation, Material Moving</option>
<option value="protective">Protective Service</option>
<option value="sales">Sales</option>
<option value="services">Services</option>
<option value="transport">Transportation</option> 
</select>
```

I also have  a JSON data set which lists occupations by gender and median earnings:

For example

```
var jobs= 
{
  "Sheet1": [
    {
      "Occupation": "Transportation ",
      "male median earnings": 24,751,
      "female median earnings": 31,981,
      "difference in pay": -7,230
    },
    {
      "Occupation": "Services",
      "male median earnings": 24,949,
      "female median earnings": 18,228,
      "difference in pay": 6,721
    },
    {
      "Occupation": "Sales",
      "male median earnings": 81,681,
      "female median earnings": 46,801,
      "difference in pay": 34,880
    },
```

Upon clicking the submit button, I want the user to see this information:

Quick edit: instead of

```
As a man you earn $------------ annually working as a (name of the occupation) and make $ ------ more than a woman in the same profession.
```

How do I turn the statement to

```
 As a (gender selected- whether man or woman) you earn $------ annually working as a (name of occupation selected) and make $------- more or less (depending on the difference) than a (gender unselected) in the same profession?
```

when the user hits the submit button?

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/html/attributes/html-onsubmit-attribute.php https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using underscore.js and jQuery library you can achive this easily. Check attached plunker here.
https://plnkr.co/edit/spwDhAAoifc2B4jPdK9m?p=preview

```
var jobs = {
    "Sheet1": [{
        "Occupation": "Transportation ",
        "male_median_earnings": "24,751",
        "female_median_earnings": "31,981",
        "difference_in_pay": "-7,230"
      }, {
        "Occupation": "Services",
        "male_median_earnings": "24,949",
        "female_median_earnings": "18,228",
        "difference_in_pay": "6,721"
      }, {
        "Occupation": "Sales",
        "male_median_earnings": "81,681",
        "female_median_earnings": "46,801",
        "difference_in_pay": "34,880"
      }]
    }
    $('.show-message').on('click tap', function(){
      var gender = $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val()
          var occupation = $('select.occupation-input').val()
          var item = _.findWhere(jobs.Sheet1, {Occupation : occupation})
          alert("As a man you earn $"+ item.male_median_earnings +" annually working as a " + occupation +" and make $"+ item.difference_in_pay +" more than a woman in the same profession.")
    })
```

Comment: Arun thank you so much. I am ever so grateful for your kindness. Spent two sleepless nights, trying to figure out the code.

Comment: Would you recommend any tutorials for javascript, especially the function you wrote, I am a beginner, and really want to understand how javascript works.

Comment: Really i'm not good at recommending it.  And the function i'm using its utility provided by underscore.js. https://developer.mozilla.org, http://www.html5rocks.com, http://htmldog.com/guides/javascript.